# Cálculo em % entre cargas horárias PHP

Tags: php

Preciso calcular a aderência realizada, entre duas cargas horárias.

- Carga 1: Carga realizada é o horário de fim - o horário de inicio
- Carga 2: Carga programada é o horário de fim programada - o horário de inicio programado.

no fim preciso do percentual `0.95 por exemplo` Carga 1 / Carga 2 no excel isso funciona no Javascript também mas no PHP estou tendo problemas.

Dei um print nos dados:

```
Realizado: 2016-10-24 15:10:00 - 2016-10-24 07:39:12 = Carga1: 07:30:48
Programado: 15:10:00 - 07:00:00 = Carga2: 08:10:00
Percentual: 0.875
```

*O Formato do realizado vem com data e o programado somente o tempo, tentei deixar os dois no mesmo formato mas não deu certo.

Estou indo por este caminho:

```
$date1 = strtotime($ponto_inicio);
$date2 = strtotime($ponto_fim);
$realizado = date( 'H:i:s', abs( $date2 - $date1 ) );

$date3 = strtotime($hora_inicio);
$date4 = strtotime($hora_fim);
$programado = date( 'H:i:s', abs( $date4 - $date3 ) );

$percentual =  $realizado / $programado;
```

Os resultados de 100% estão ok mas quando sai disso o resultado sempre é `0.88` para casos de horário programado igual e realizado diferentes.

O que está errado?

Comment: Pode iincluir no exemplo exemplos do $ponto_inicio, $ponto_fim, $hora_inicio e $hora_fim que estão sendo utilizados?

Comment: Coloquei os dados utilizados.

Answer (score 1):

Ola!
Tente:

```
$percentual = ($realizado * 100)/$programado;
```

Comment: Não deu certo, neste caso todos os resultados aprecem iguais.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui o resultado convertendo as cargas para segundos, usando o `date_paser();`

```
$date1 = strtotime($ponto_inicio);
$date2 = strtotime($ponto_fim);
$realizado = date( 'H:i:s', abs( $date2 - $date1 ) );
$realizado = date_parse($realizado);
$realizado = $realizado['hour'] * 3600 + $realizado['minute'] * 60 + $realizado['second'];

$date3 = strtotime($hora_inicio);
$date4 = strtotime($hora_fim);
$programado = date( 'H:i:s', abs( $date4 - $date3 ) );
$programado = date_parse($programado);
$programado = $programado['hour'] * 3600 + $programado['minute'] * 60 + $programado['second'];

$percentual =  $realizado / $programado;
```

Desta forma o percentual saiu certinho, não sei se a estrutura esta totalmente correta.

Comment: então não se trata de cálculo percentual...

Comment: Resultado *100 + "%" é o percentual sim, só não está formatado, não entendi o que quis dizer, aliás no banco depois se for fazer um AVG do resultado se tiver "%" não é possível, desta forma é mais prático.